# Check if property can be set to a different value or is read-only

Tags: vba

Is there a way to determine in VBA if a property of an object can be set to a different value?

Like check if the property is writable or is not read-only?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check a property is to highlight it and with the cursor in the VBA editor and press Shift + F2.  This will bring up its definition in the object browser and it will tell you there whether it is read only or not.

The following screenshot is of the `workbook.worksheets.count` property.

[image]

You could in code check for read-only by suspending errors trying to set the property and then checking the property.  Ie

```
iCountCheck = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count = 123   'Something that doesn't already equal iCountCheck
On Error Goto 0

If iCountCheck <> 123
   MsgBox "This is not read only"
Else
   MsgBox "This is read only"
End If
```

Comment: This is sort of what I needed. I am working in MS Access and there is a macro in the background that is designed to reset a particular property each time the object closes. The problem is that when an object is half-opened and terminated without opening, the property is not writable. I thought if I put a check in to test for this, I could prevent the error.  But your solution is  to catch the error as it occurs. I will read up on this a little bit more.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'half-opens', do you some initialising of the object and if it is terminated early it simply doesn't reset the initial values? And you want to check if this has occurred?  A property is either read-only or not it shouldn't change depending on the code.  Are you able to provide a little more detail?

Comment: Sorry it took a while to get back. I have a report that uses a filter with an open parameter. Because I use filters extensively, the filter gets overwritten. I want to reset the filter back to the original filter on each close, so I reset it in VBA. Every time the report is opened, MS Access prompts for input into the parameter. If you hit escape at the prompt, an error occurs saying the filter property is read-only.  I even put a check in there to rewrite the filter only if there is a change, but that meant nothing.

Comment: Hmmm. It might be best to close off this question and start a new one with the specifics of the problem.  I'm not too familiar with MS Access and it seems like there is a bit more to your question.